# Clone VM connected to domain with CRM 2011 on Windows 2008 R2 SP1

Tags: active-directory, crm

After copying VM with CRM 2011 I've changed server name, performed actions in this article:
[http://weblogs.asp.net/navaidakhtar/Microsoft-Dynamics-CRM-2011-*2F00*-4.0-Configuration-in-Case-of-Machine-rename-*2F00*-CRM-Database-server-change-*2F00*-Domain-Controller-Change](http://weblogs.asp.net/navaidakhtar/Microsoft-Dynamics-CRM-2011-_2F00_-4.0-Configuration-in-Case-of-Machine-rename-_2F00_-CRM-Database-server-change-_2F00_-Domain-Controller-Change)

and now I'm trying to create new organization, but it fails at verification step, for CRM point it says (SQL and Reporting Server points are OK):

> Name translation: Could not find the name or insufficient right to see
>   name. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80072116)

Domain account, which I used for logging in, has all necessary permission (actually, it included into Domain Admins and Enterprise Admins groups), but I can't understand, which name wizard wants to find.

In original VM I can create new organization without any troubles.

Comment: `After copying VM with CRM 2011`  <-- Yeah, that's probably your problem.  You can't just clone a VM and slap it back in the same domain it came from.  All the unique identifiers stay the same when you clone a machine, so it presents to AD as the same computer as the original clone.  Maybe you should start with what you're trying to accomplish by cloning this VM, and ask how to do that properly.

Comment: I've recreated VM in Hyper-V with old vhd image and as I understand, it should create new VM with new ids for hardware (new MAC and etc), so it similar to install OS on one PC, and copy the image to others. I don't think it is a bad practice for quick creating of clear CRM VM. I need it for quick creation of DEV machine with CRM.

Comment: @6a6kin You *cannot* clone a domain-joined machine and expect it to work. Use sysprep first.

Comment: @NathanC Thank you for useful tool, I will use it for erasing all vm dependent data. But it didn't solved my issue. It was in out-dated AD Groups guids in CRM DB. I'll try to explain in answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found out the root cause of this problem.
Validation checks failed to fetch AD Groups (PrivReportingGroup, SQLAccessGroup, etc) by GUIDs, which are stored in MSCRM_Config database (I clones old VM, so groups were deleted).

To fix this, I replaced group guids with this query and validation check was passed.

```
UPDATE [MSCRM_CONFIG].[dbo].[ConfigSettings]
SET PrivilegeReportGroupId = '<guid>'
    ,PrivilegeUserGroupId = '<guid>'
    ,ReportingGroupId = '<guid>'
    ,SqlAccessGroupId = '<guid>'
GO
```

Thanks all for helping.